# AddAsync( IEntity Intuit.Ipp.Data.Customer ) doesn't initiate callback method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, intuit-partner-platform

I'm passing in an object that's already been transformed into a fully formed QBO Customer Entity. I'd like to use the AddAsync(IEntity) method because it returns the same object from QBO with it's ID (or an Error).

With the code below, I can see that it successfully works at adding the object to QBO, but my callback method never gets called and I only see two of the following DataService error messages and a System.dll error message in my output:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Intuit.Ipp.DataService.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Intuit.Ipp.DataService.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.dll

Here's my code:

```
    public void Add([NotNull] Sales.Customer input)
    {
        try
        {
            _customer = input;
            var qboInput = QboCustomerTranslate.Current.ToQuickbooksModel(input);
            QboAuth.AuthService.OnAddAsyncCompleted += OnAddCallBackUpdateQboId;
            QboAuth.AuthService.AddAsync(qboInput);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public void OnAddCallBackUpdateQboId(object sender, CallCompletedEventArgs<IEntity> e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            if (e.Entity != null)
            {
                var customer = e.Entity as Customer;
                if (customer != null)
                {
                    using (var db = DatabaseManager.Current.NewDatabase())
                    {
                        _customer.Notes = e.Error.Message;
                        if (!customer.Id.IsEmpty())
                        {
                            _customer.QuickbooksId = customer.Id.AsInt();
                        }
                        _customer.Save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Entity != null)
            {
                var customer = e.Entity as Customer;
                if (customer != null)
                {
                    using (var db = DatabaseManager.Current.NewDatabase())
                    {
                        if (!customer.Id.IsEmpty())
                        {
                            _customer.QuickbooksId = customer.Id.AsInt();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My request Json looks like:

```
{
  "BillAddr": {
    "Line1": "77 TestStreet",
    "Line2": "",
    "City": "TestingsVilleTown",
    "Country": "USA",
    "CountrySubDivisionCode": "TT",
    "PostalCode": "77887"
  },
  "GivenName": "TFirst",
  "FamilyName": "TLast",
  "CompanyName": "Test22",
  "DisplayName": "Test22",
  "PrimaryPhone": {
    "DeviceType": "Primary",
    "FreeFormNumber": "7778884567"
  },
  "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
    "Address": "Test22@Test.com"
  }
}
```

My response Json looks like:

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "Taxable": false,
    "BillAddr": {
      "Id": "9495",
      "Line1": "77 TestStreet",
      "City": "TestingsVilleTown",
      "Country": "USA",
      "CountrySubDivisionCode": "TT",
      "PostalCode": "77887",
      "Lat": "INVALID",
      "Long": "INVALID"
    },
    "Job": false,
    "BillWithParent": false,
    "Balance": 0,
    "BalanceWithJobs": 0,
    "PreferredDeliveryMethod": "Print",
    "domain": "QBO",
    "sparse": false,
    "Id": "7291",
    "SyncToken": "0",
    "MetaData": {
      "CreateTime": "2014-03-12T10:06:12-07:00",
      "LastUpdatedTime": "2014-03-12T10:06:12-07:00"
    },
    "GivenName": "TFirst",
    "FamilyName": "TLast",
    "FullyQualifiedName": "Test22",
    "CompanyName": "Test22",
    "DisplayName": "Test22",
    "PrintOnCheckName": "Test22",
    "Active": true,
    "PrimaryPhone": {
      "FreeFormNumber": "7778884567"
    },
    "PrimaryEmailAddr": {
      "Address": "Test22@Test.com"
    }
  },
  "time": "2014-03-12T10:06:11.796-07:00"
}
```

-Edit-

These seem to be the related lines from the Tracelog:

```
WebDev.WebServer40.exe Information: 0 : Info -- 03-13-2014 15:23:37 --  - 0 - Void AddAsyncompleted(System.Object, Intuit.Ipp.Core.AsyncCallCompletedEventArgs) - Finished Executing event AddAsyncompleted in AsyncService object.
WebDev.WebServer40.exe Information: 0 : Info -- 03-13-2014 15:23:37 --  - 0 - Void AddAsyncCompleted(System.Object, Intuit.Ipp.Core.CallCompletedEventArgs`1[Intuit.Ipp.Data.IEntity]) - Finished Executing Method add Async.
WebDev.WebServer40.exe Error: 0 : Error -- 03-13-2014 15:23:37 --  - 0 - Void AddAsyncompleted(System.Object, Intuit.Ipp.Core.AsyncCallCompletedEventArgs) - Intuit.Ipp.Exception.IdsException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
WebDev.WebServer40.exe Information: 0 : Info -- 03-13-2014 15:23:37 --  - 0 - Void AddAsyncCompleted(System.Object, Intuit.Ipp.Core.CallCompletedEventArgs`1[Intuit.Ipp.Data.IEntity]) - Finished Executing Method add Async.
```

---

Simple Fix - I was having this problem since I wasn't storing my DataService.

Comment: Can you please enable devkit logger to capture the details of this exception. Please refer - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/logging#Request_and_Response_Log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataService.DataService service = new DataService.DataService(context);

bool isAdded = false;

 // Used to signal the waiting test thread that a async operation have completed.    
        System.Threading.ManualResetEvent manualEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        // Async callback events are anonomous and are in the same scope as the test code,    
        // and therefore have access to the manualEvent variable.    
        service.OnAddAsyncCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            isAdded = true;
            manualEvent.Set();
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                exp = e.Error;
            }
            if (exp == null)
            {
                if (e.Entity != null)
                {
                    actual = (T)e.Entity;
                }
            }
        };

        // Call the service method
        service.AddAsync(entity);

        manualEvent.WaitOne(30000, false); Thread.Sleep(10000);
        manualEvent.Reset();
```

The above is an example using anonymous type. See if this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Turns out this isn't the answer, but when I was testing it I finally noticed that every my QboAuth class was creating a new DataService everytime I called it. It works now and calling the manual event does seem pretty handy.